# How to Decompile FMX file

Tags: oracle, reverse-engineering, oracleforms, decompiler

I would like to know how to decompile a fmx file in order to make some changes into an application without source code, we just have the .fmx (Oracle 9i) file and really need the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's no tool for decompile an FMX. You have to contact Oracle and ask them to do that, they will send you the fmb.

Comment: I hope you were kidding with the contact Oracle part?

Comment: Nope, not kidding. This happened with a friend and he did it.

Comment: https://github.com/witchi/fmx.6.decompiler

Answer (score 1):

There are no tools to decompile an FMX. A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4271738/92837) mentions the reason(!) for the lack of a decompiler.

Looking around other sites you'll get the same response - [there is no fmx decompiler](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1056938)

Comment: Thanks for the info now i know that there is no decompiler