# How to convert .rep files back to .rdf in Reports Designer in oracle report?

Tags: oracle, reportbuilder, report-designer

I lost my .rdf file but i have my .rep file . Is there a way that i can convert rep file into rdf file?. Anyone got the idea?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why there is no oracle Forms or Reports decompiler ? (Technically)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271738/why-there-is-no-oracle-forms-or-reports-decompiler-technically)

Comment: for me, this question not the duplicate because i have still not get the answer.How to get back my .rdf files from .rep?.

Comment: You *have* got the answer. The answer is no.